# Is there any data structure can do random insert, random delete and interval summation with O(log n) time complexity？

Tags: data-structures

1. Insert(k, x), insert element x in the k-th position
2. Delete(k), delete element in the k-th position
3. Summation(l, r), calculate the sum of the element from l-th position to r-th position

I used Segment Tree to resolve interval summation in O(log n), but it seems that Segment Tree can not do random insert and random delete elegantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use something called Implicit Treaps.
https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/treap.html

Comment: Many thanks! That's inspired me a lot.

Comment: Yeah no problem. There are tremendous interesting applications of Treaps. The data structure is pure joy to play with. Let me know if you'd like to see some interesting application problems on the same.